# To switch two areas in a circular linked list (JAVA)

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

I am writing a code that for swapping a certain area of a circular linked list with another one, like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

..↑.↑.↑...↑.↑.↑....

1 6 7 8 5 2 3 4 9 0

..↑.↑.↑...↑.↑.↑....
```

So I have a question about the CLL: in the example I gave, if there is a rear pointing at the last digit zero and zero.next also points to one, what can I do for accomplishing the swap? Should I create a new node pointer or it's just ok to deal with only the rear pointer? I am not quite familiar with the property of CLL, thanks.

Comment: What circular linked list are you using? Is it one you wrote yourself, or is it from a library somewhere?

Comment: The one I wrote for myself, sir.

Comment: @StuartMarks I've found a solution which made temporary nodes pointing to those key points as makrs, then do a re-organization. However, for every time I have to draw a picture (actually not small) to help me think which error go where... Is there a easier way to help doing this kind of thing?

Comment: Most textbooks that deal with complicated linked structures (e.g., balanced trees) use a lot of diagrams. But Stack Overflow is very code-driven, so if you really want help you should post some code and maybe supplement it with a diagram if you think it'll help.